# How to write EqProp instances for quickBatch tests?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I've come across 2 examples:

```
data List a = 
    Nil 
  | Cons a (List a) 
  deriving (Eq, Show) 

instance Eq a => EqProp (List a) where
  (=-=) = eq
```

```
newtype ZipList' a = 
  ZipList' (List a) 
  deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Eq a => EqProp (ZipList' a) where 
  xs =-= ys = xs' `eq` ys' 
    where xs' = let (ZipList' l) = xs 
                in take' 3000 l 
          ys' = let (ZipList' l) = ys 
                in take' 3000 l 

take' :: Int -> List a -> List a
take' n (Cons a as) = Cons a (take' (n - 1) as)
```

(There are also `Functor` and `Applicative` instances, which are being tested):

```
main :: IO ()
main =
  hspec $ do
    describe "List" $ do
      it "Functor" $
        property (quickBatch $ functor (undefined :: List (Int, Float, String)))
      it "Applicative" $
        property
          (quickBatch $ applicative (undefined :: List (Int, Float, String)))
    describe "ZipList'" $ do
      it "Functor" $
        property
          (quickBatch $ functor (undefined :: ZipList' (Int, Float, String)))
      it "Applicative" $
        property
          (quickBatch $ applicative (undefined :: ZipList' (Int, Float, String)))
```

As I understand, we take 3000 values, because otherwise tests will chase the infinite lists forever. But in the first example, there is an infinite list too, isn't there? So why is `EqProp` trivial in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property testing library (I know quickCheck, but not quickBatch) should be managing data size when values are generated, not when values are compared. Limiting the size in your equality check is a bad idea, because it means that

1. Data generation can be infinite, so your test can be non terminating BEFORE it gets to the equality check
2. You can have false positives where the 3001st element differs

Since there is already and instance for `[]` and `ZipList` is a `newtype` we can get the instance for free like so.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}

deriving instance Eq a => EqProp (ZipList' a)
```